# Is there a way to get the labels' width and height before drawing?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-label

I am using leaflet with leaflet label. Sometimes the markers overlap, which is bad for the UX and therefore I have implemented the following Spiderfier functionality:

```
/*Geometry*/
//Abstract Shape function capable to check intersection
function Shape(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);
    this.initialize("Type", "Default");
    //Let's know whether intersection is symmetric
    this.initialize("Symmetric", true);
    this.initialize("Intersects", function (shape) {
        return false;
    });
}
//These rectangles have two horizontal and two vertical sides
function HorizontalVerticalRectangle(params) {
    params.Type = "HorizontalVerticalRectangle";
    var self = this;
    if (typeof params.Intersects !== "function") {
        //Default Intersects function
        params.Intersects = function (shape) {
            //If the two shapes have the same types and self is not to the right, left, bottom or top compared to shape then they intersect each-other
            if (shape.Type === self.Type) {
                return !((self.TopLeft.x > shape.BottomRight.x) ||
                         (self.BottomRight.x < shape.TopLeft.x) ||
                         (self.TopLeft.y > shape.BottomRight.y) ||
                         (self.BottomRight.y < shape.TopLeft.y));
                //In case of top half circles, we need to make sure that the horizontal square collides the circle and in the top half
            } else if (shape.Type === "TopHalfCircle") {
                return (self.TopLeft.y <= shape.Center.y) && HorizontalVerticalRectangle.prototype.CollidesCircle(self, shape.Center.x, shape.Center.y, shape.Diameter / 2);
            }
            //Not implemented
            return false;
        };
    }
    Shape.call(this, params);
    this.initialize("TopLeft", { x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.initialize("BottomRight", { x: 0, y: 0 });
    //Make sure the x and y coordinates are kept as floats
    this.TopLeft.x = parseFloat(this.TopLeft.x);
    this.TopLeft.y = parseFloat(this.TopLeft.y);
    this.BottomRight.x = parseFloat(this.BottomRight.x);
    this.BottomRight.y = parseFloat(this.BottomRight.y);
    //Coordinate setters
    this.setTopLeftX = function (x) {
        self.TopLeft.x = parseFloat(x);
    };
    this.setTopLeftY = function (y) {
        self.TopLeft.y = parseFloat(y);
    };
    this.setBottomRightX = function (x) {
        self.BottomRight.x = parseFloat(x);
    };
    this.setBottomRightY = function (y) {
        self.BottomRight.y = parseFloat(y);
    };
}
HorizontalVerticalRectangle.prototype.CollidesCircle = function (horizontalRectangle, centerX, centerY, radius) {
    var deltaX = centerX - Math.max(horizontalRectangle.TopLeft.x, Math.min(centerX, horizontalRectangle.BottomRight.x));
    var deltaY = centerY - Math.max(horizontalRectangle.TopLeft.y, Math.min(centerY, horizontalRectangle.BottomRight.y));
    return Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2) <= Math.pow(radius, 2);
};
//These are circles where the center has the maximum y and the shape is upwards on screens
function TopHalfCircle(params) {
    params.Type = "TopHalfCircle";
    var self = this;
    if (typeof params.Intersects !== "function") {
        //Default Intersects function
        params.Intersects = function (shape) {
            //If the two shapes have identical type, none of them is above (below in coordinates) the other by more than the other's radius and the full circles intersect, 
            //then the half circles intersect each-other
            if (shape.Type === self.Type) {
                return ((self.Center.y - shape.Center.y) < (self.Diameter / 2)) &&
                       ((shape.Center.y - self.Center.y) < (shape.Diameter / 2)) &&
                       (Math.pow(self.Center.x - shape.Center.x, 2) + Math.pow(self.Center.y - shape.Center.y, 2) < Math.pow(((self.Diameter + shape.Diameter) / 2), 2));
                //In case of top horizontal vertical rectangle, we need to make sure that the horizontal square collides the circle and in the top half
            } else if (shape.Type === "HorizontalVerticalRectangle") {
                return (shape.TopLeft.y <= self.Center.y) && HorizontalVerticalRectangle.prototype.CollidesCircle(shape, self.Center.x, self.Center.y, self.Diameter / 2);
            }
            //Not Implemented
            return false;
        };
    }
    Shape.call(this, params);
    this.initialize("Center", { x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.initialize("Diameter", 0);
    //Make sure the coordinates and diameter are kept as floats
    this.Center.x = parseFloat(this.Center.x);
    this.Center.y = parseFloat(this.Center.y);
    this.Diameter = parseFloat(this.Diameter);
    //Setters
    this.setCenterX = function (x) {
        self.Center.x = parseFloat(x);
    };
    this.setCenterY = function (y) {
        self.Center.y = parseFloat(y);
    };
    this.setDiameter = function (d) {
        self.Diameter = parseFloat(d);
    };
}
//Placement strategies for markers, but they can be used for different purposes as well
var PlacementStrategies = {
    //This function finds groups of shapes seeing which shape intersects which other shape
    Group: function (shapes, comparator) {
        if (typeof comparator !== "function") {
            comparator = function () {
                return true;
            };
        }
        //This variable is empty at start, but at the end will hold the shape groups
        var groups = [];
        //Traverse the shapes to build the groups
        for (var shapeIndex in shapes) {
            //This variable will hold false if the shape does not fit into any existing group and the group index otherwise
            var foundGroup = false;
            //Traverse the groups to find whether a group where the shape fits in already exists
            for (var groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < groups.length; groupIndex++) {
                //Traverse the shapes of the current group to see whether any of them intersects the shape
                for (var innerShapeIndex = 0; (groupIndex < groups.length) && (innerShapeIndex < groups[groupIndex].length) ; innerShapeIndex++) {
                    //If shape intersects with the current group's current shape, then set foundGroup and exit two for cycles
                    if (Shape.prototype.intersects(shapes[shapeIndex], shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]])) {
                        foundGroup = groupIndex;
                        innerShapeIndex = groups[groupIndex].length;
                        groupIndex = groups.length;
                    }
                }
            }
            //If the shape does not fit into any groups, then we create its own group
            if (foundGroup === false) {
                groups.push([shapeIndex]);
                //Otherwise we search for the location where the shape fits best
            } else {
                //Desired location. If it results in false, then the shape will be pushed to the end, otherwise it will be inserted at insertIndex
                var insertIndex = false;
                //Traverse the shapes of the found group to find the desired location to insert
                for (var innerShapeIndex = 0; innerShapeIndex < groups[foundGroup].length; innerShapeIndex++) {
                    //If the shape to be inserted is "smaller" than the found group's current shape, then store the index and quit the cycle
                    if (!comparator(shapes[groups[foundGroup][innerShapeIndex]], shapes[shapeIndex])) {
                        insertIndex = innerShapeIndex;
                        innerShapeIndex = groups[foundGroup].length;
                    }
                }
                //Insert the shape into the desired location or to the end if there was no desired middle location
                if (insertIndex === false) {
                    groups[foundGroup].push(shapeIndex);
                } else {
                    groups[foundGroup].splice(insertIndex, 0, shapeIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        return groups;
    },
    //This function merges shape groups if they intersect each-other
    MergeGroup: function (shapes, groups, merged, comparator) {
        if (typeof comparator !== "function") {
            comparator = function () {
                return true;
            };
        }
        //This time we merge the contents of the groups into the first index
        mergeIssued = true;
        while (mergeIssued) {
            //There was no merge issued yet
            mergeIssued = false;
            //Traverse the main groups
            for (var mergeIndex in merged) {
                //Traverse the groups to merge with
                for (var innerMergeIndex in merged[mergeIndex]) {
                    //If the group to merge with is empty, then it was already parsed
                    if ((merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]]) && (merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]].length > 0)) {
                        //Traverse the inner groups of the inner group
                        for (var toMove in merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]]) {
                            //Move them if they are not yet present in the main merge group
                            if (merged[mergeIndex].indexOf(merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][toMove]) === -1) {
                                merged[mergeIndex].push(merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][toMove]);
                                mergeIssued = true;
                            }
                            //Remove the content of the inner group to avoid duplicates
                            merged[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]] = [];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Traverse the merge groups to move the shapes
        for (var mergeIndex in merged) {
            //Traverse the inner groups where we read the shapes from
            for (var innerMergeIndex in merged[mergeIndex]) {
                //Traverse the shapes of the inner group
                for (var shapeIndex in groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]]) {
                    //If the shape is not yet present in the target group, we move it
                    if (groups[mergeIndex].indexOf(groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][shapeIndex]) === -1) {
                        //A variable which will hold the index of insertion or false, if the element should be the lasts
                        var insertLocation = false;
                        //Traverse the shapes of the target group to find the correct location
                        for (var targetIndex = 0; (insertLocation === false) && (targetIndex < groups[mergeIndex].length) ; targetIndex++) {
                            //If the shape located at the current index is not "smaller" than the shape to be inserted, then we found the target location
                            if (!comparator(shapes[groups[mergeIndex][targetIndex]], shapes[groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][shapeIndex]])) {
                                insertLocation = targetIndex;
                            }
                        }
                        //If there was no "bigger" element, then push at the end of the array
                        if (insertLocation === false) {
                            groups[mergeIndex].push(groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][shapeIndex]);
                            //Otherwise insert it to the correct location
                        } else {
                            groups[mergeIndex].splice(insertLocation, 0, groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]][shapeIndex]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Clear the group where we moved the shapes from
                groups[merged[mergeIndex][innerMergeIndex]] = [];
            }
        }

        //We copy the non-empty groups into another container
        var finalGroups = [];
        for (var groupIndex in groups) {
            if (groups[groupIndex].length > 0) {
                finalGroups.push(groups[groupIndex]);
            }
        }
        //And return it
        return finalGroups;
    },
    //This strategy moves rectangles inside a group into a semi circle upwards on the screen
    SemiCircleHorizontalRectangles: function (shapes, groups) {
        //If groups is falsy, then this is the first try
        if (!groups) {
            //Which means that we need to create it by calling PlacementStrategies.Group with the comparator desired here
            groups = PlacementStrategies.Group(shapes, function (shape1, shape2) {
                //The shapes to the left are "smaller" to minimize line collisions
                return shape1.TopLeft.x < shape2.TopLeft.x;
            });
        }
        //This will hold top circles of the groups of shapes
        var groupTopCircles = [];
        //Traverse the raw groups
        for (var groupIndex in groups) {
            //We need to know the center of the circle, which will be the middle point of the horizontal coordinates and the lowest point in the circle
            var maxY = false;
            var minX = false;
            var maxX = false;
            //We need to know the half periphery to calculate the diameter
            var halfPeriphery = 0;
            //Traverse the shapes in the group
            for (var innerShapeIndex in groups[groupIndex]) {
                //Calculate the values where we calculate the center coordinates from
                if ((minX === false) || (minX > shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].TopLeft.x)) {
                    minX = shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].TopLeft.x;
                }
                if ((maxX === false) || (maxX < shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.x)) {
                    maxX = shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.x;
                }
                if ((maxY === false) || (maxY < shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.y)) {
                    maxY = shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.y;
                }
                //Add the length of the diagonal of the shape to halfPeriphery
                halfPeriphery += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.x - shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].TopLeft.x, 2) + Math.pow(shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].BottomRight.y - shapes[groups[groupIndex][innerShapeIndex]].TopLeft.y, 2));
            }
            //Add the half circle to the container
            groupTopCircles[groupIndex] = new TopHalfCircle({ Center: { x: (minX + maxX) / 2, y: maxY }, Diameter: 2 * halfPeriphery / Math.PI });
        }
        //Container for groups to be merged
        var merged;
        //Traverse all the shapes
        for (var halfCircleIndex = 0; halfCircleIndex < groupTopCircles.length; halfCircleIndex++) {
            var s1 = (groups[halfCircleIndex].length === 1) ? shapes[groups[halfCircleIndex][0]] : groupTopCircles[halfCircleIndex];
        //Traverse the "later" shapes
            for (var secondHalfCircleIndex = halfCircleIndex + 1; secondHalfCircleIndex < groupTopCircles.length; secondHalfCircleIndex++) {
                var s2 = (groups[secondHalfCircleIndex].length === 1) ? shapes[groups[secondHalfCircleIndex][0]] : groupTopCircles[secondHalfCircleIndex];
                //If the two half circles intersect each-other, then merge them
                if (Shape.prototype.intersects(s1, s2)) {
                    if (!merged) {
                        merged = {};
                    }
                    if (!merged[halfCircleIndex]) {
                        merged[halfCircleIndex] = [];
                    }
                    //We always merge into the first group
                    merged[halfCircleIndex].push(secondHalfCircleIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        //If there was a merge then we do the effective merging and repeat this strategy for the resulting half-circles
        if (merged) {
            return PlacementStrategies.SemiCircleHorizontalRectangles(shapes, PlacementStrategies.MergeGroup(shapes, groups, merged, function (shape1, shape2) {
                //We will order horizontal-verticle rectangles here, we might refactor this function to get a comparator instead later
                return shape1.TopLeft.x < shape2.TopLeft.x;
            }));
        }
        //Angle iterator for the half circle
        var angle;
        //The amount of step with the angle iterator
        var angleStep;
        //Traverse the groups to change the coordinates
        for (var groupIndex in groups) {
            //If the group has a single element, then we jump over it
            if (groups[groupIndex].length > 1) {
                //Initialize the angle iterator and calculate its step size
                angle = Math.PI;
                angleStep = angle / (groups[groupIndex].length - 1);
                //Traverse the shapes
                for (var shapeIndex in groups[groupIndex]) {
                    //The translation is calculated based on circle coordinates
                    var translation = {
                        x: groupTopCircles[groupIndex].Center.x + (groupTopCircles[groupIndex].Diameter * Math.cos(angle) / 2),
                        y: groupTopCircles[groupIndex].Center.y + (groupTopCircles[groupIndex].Diameter * Math.sin(angle) / 2)
                    };
                    //The middle of the rectangles will place at the desired point and we need the middle coordinates for that
                    var halfDiffX = (shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].BottomRight.x - shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].TopLeft.x) / 2;
                    var halfDiffY = (shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].BottomRight.y - shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].TopLeft.y) / 2;
                    //Calculate the new bounds of the rectangle and step the iterator
                    shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].setTopLeftX(translation.x - halfDiffX);
                    shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].setTopLeftY(translation.y - halfDiffY);
                    shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].setBottomRightX(translation.x + halfDiffX);
                    shapes[groups[groupIndex][shapeIndex]].setBottomRightY(translation.y + halfDiffY);
                    angle += angleStep;
                }
            }
        }
        return shapes;
    }
};
//General intersects function for shapes, which gets two shapes and checks whether they intersect each-other
Shape.prototype.intersects = function (shape1, shape2) {
    //If the first shape is symmetric and the types of shapes match, it is enough to check a single direction of intersection
    //Otherwise we need to check both directions
    return ((shape1.Symmetric) && (shape1.Type === shape2.Type)) ? (shape1.Intersects(shape2)) : (shape1.Intersects(shape2) || shape2.Intersects(shape1));
};
/*Geometry*/
/*Spiderfier*/
function Spiderfier(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);
    var self = this;
    var isSpiderfied = false;
    this.defaultFunction = function () { };
    //Custom Spiderfy Events
    this.initialize("OnSpiderfy", this.defaultFunction, true);
    this.initialize("OnUnspiderfy", this.defaultFunction, true);
    this.initialize("rows", [], true);
    this.initialize("cm", function () {
        return cachedMarkers;
    }, true);
    this.initialize("options", {});
    this.SpiderLines = {};
    this.isCurrentlySpiderfied = function () {
        return isSpiderfied;
    };
    this.refreshRows = function (r, stopRefresh) {
        rows = r;
        if (isSpiderfied && (!stopRefresh)) {
            self.spiderfy();
        }
    };
    this.spiderfy = function (r) {
        if (r) {
            self.refreshRows(r, true);
        }
        params.OnSpiderfy(rows, self);
        isSpiderfied = true;
    };
    this.unspiderfy = function (r) {
        if (r) {
            self.refreshRows(r, true);
        }
        params.OnUnspiderfy(rows, self);
        isSpiderfied = false;
    };
    //Handles marker draw and spiderfying
    this.drawAndSpiderfy = function (r, o) {
        //First handle the spiderfy thing
        if (o) {
            self.options = o;
        }
        if (self.isCurrentlySpiderfied()) {
            self.spiderfy(r, params.cm());
            drawSpiderMarkers(r, params.cm(), self);
        } else {
            self.unspiderfy(r, params.cm());
        }
        //And then draw the markers
        drawMarkers(rows, options);
    };
}
//Gets the rectangles of the markers
function markersToRectangles(rows) {
    var shapes = [];
    var lowPoint;
    for (var rowIndex in rows) {
        //Convert the geographical point of the marker into graphical point
        lowPoint = map.latLngToLayerPoint(L.latLng(rows[rowIndex].RealLat, rows[rowIndex].RealLon));
        shapes.push(new HorizontalVerticalRectangle({
            TopLeft: { x: lowPoint.x - 18, y: lowPoint.y - 44 },
            BottomRight: { x: lowPoint.x + 18 + 0, y: lowPoint.y }
        }));
    }
    return shapes;
}
//Spiderfies rectangles with half circle strategy
function RectangleHalfCircleSpiderfy(rows, spdfr) {
    //Initialize real latitude and longitude if not already done so
    for (var rowIndex in rows) {
        if (!rows[rowIndex].RealLat) {
            rows[rowIndex].RealLat = rows[rowIndex].Lat;
            rows[rowIndex].RealLon = rows[rowIndex].Lon;
        }
    }
    //Gather the desired rectangles
    var rectangles = PlacementStrategies.SemiCircleHorizontalRectangles(markersToRectangles(rows));
    //Store the geographic coordinates
    for (var rowIndex in rectangles) {
        //Convert graphical coordinates into geographic coordinates
        var location = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(rectangles[rowIndex].TopLeft.x + 14, rectangles[rowIndex].BottomRight.y));
        rows[rowIndex].Lat = location.lat;
        rows[rowIndex].Lon = location.lng;
    }
}
function normalUnspiderfy(rows, spiderfier) {
    for (var rowIndex in rows) {
        if (rows[rowIndex].RealLat !== undefined) {
            rows[rowIndex].Lat = rows[rowIndex].RealLat;
            rows[rowIndex].Lon = rows[rowIndex].RealLon;
            delete rows[rowIndex].RealLat;
            delete rows[rowIndex].RealLon;
        }
    }
    for (var lineIndex in spiderfier.SpiderLines) {
        map.removeLayer(spiderfier.SpiderLines[lineIndex].polyLine);
    }
    spiderfier.SpiderLines = {};
}
//Draws spider markers
function drawSpiderMarkers(rows, cachedMarkers, spiderfier) {
    //For each row...
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        //If real location exists and differs from the display location and there is either no spider line yet or points to a different location than the expected one
        if (rows[i].RealLat && rows[i].RealLon &&
            ((rows[i].Lat != rows[i].RealLat) || (rows[i].Lon != rows[i].RealLon)) &&
            ((!spiderfier.SpiderLines[i]) || (spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].location.Lat != rows[i].Lat) || (spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].location.Lon != rows[i].Lon))
           ) {
            //Then check whether the spider line exists and remove it if so
            if (spiderfier.SpiderLines[i]) {
                map.removeLayer(spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].polyLine);
            }
            //And generate a new spider line
            spiderfier.SpiderLines[i] = { location: new L.LatLng(rows[i].Lat, rows[i].Lon), realLocation: new L.LatLng(rows[i].RealLat, rows[i].RealLon) };
            spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].polyLine = L.polyline([spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].location, spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].realLocation]);
            spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].polyLine.options.weight = 2;
            spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].polyLine.options.color = "#5f0df1";
            spiderfier.SpiderLines[i].polyLine.addTo(map);
        }
    }
}
var spiderfier;
/*Spiderfier*/

function getStrategyName(code) {
    switch (code) {
        case 2: return "Grouped";
        case 3: return "RectangleHalfCircleSpiderfy";
        default: return "Unspecified";
    }
}

function drawStrategicMarkers(rows, drawOpt) {
    if (drawOpt.strategy < 3) {
        if (drawOpt.strategy === 2) {
            drawOpt.grouped = true;
        }
        return drawMarkers(rows, drawOpt);
    } else {
        if (!spiderfier) {
            window["spiderfier"] = new Spiderfier({
                OnSpiderfy: window[getStrategyName(drawOpt.strategy)],
                OnUnspiderfy: normalUnspiderfy,
            });
        }
        spiderfier.drawAndSpiderfy(rows);
    }
}
```

Explanation: This calculates the graphical coordinates of the marker's rectangle and finds out which rectangles belong to a group. A group will be a top half circle where markers are displayed at the periphery and when we have such half-circles, they are checked against each-other, so if they intersect each-other, then they are merged into a new group. If a group contains a single marker, then its rectangle is taken into consideration rather than its top half circle. At the end markers are translated to their desired location on their group (top half circle periphery).

This works perfectly, however, the problem is that this takes into account only the markers' rectangles and does not take into account label sizes at all (a label is displayed to the right of the corresponding marker and the two together should be considered as a single rectangle). The reason for this is very simple: I can gather label sizes, but only after everything was drawn. My question is as follows: If I know what the label will contain, is there a reliable formula with which I can gather the bounds and limits of the label container, so that I could check for it to not overlap with other markers or labels as well?

After labels are generated, this extremely hacky way is how I could gather information about the labels' size:

```
function getLabelSize(index) {
    var labelContext = $(".leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-label:eq(" + index + ")");
    return {width: labelContext.width(), height: labelContext.height()};
}
```

To draw the markers, measure the labels and then redraw the markers just to get the label sizes this way is so hacky that I rather allow labels to intersect markers or other labels, which is a sad decision. Therefore I wonder: is there a way to get the width and height of a label which was not yet drawn based on its future content?

The content looks like this:

```
<div class="leaflet-label  leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-label-right" style="z-index: 540; transform: translate3d(912px, 500px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
    <p class="orange">34534</p>
    <p>3343453</p>
</div>
```

Of course, that div has padding and border, but I will be able to add the needed values if I am able to read the inner width and height somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I know what the label will contain, is there a reliable formula with which I can gather the bounds and limits of the label container?

No.

In HTML, you cannot know the [computed dimensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) of a block element before that block element gets added to the DOM. This is due to a variety of reasons; mainly the fact that there *might* be lots of different (non-explicit) CSS selectors that *might* apply to that block element when it gets added. Plus user-agent stylesheets, GPU font rendering, DPI font size, etc etc etc.

I researched this when working on [Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision).

> this extremely hacky way is how I could gather information about the labels' size

Please don't. Use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) *after the element has been added to the DOM*.

You are free to remove that element from the DOM (or to remove the Leaflet layer, as it will have the same effect) within the same render frame. You can add an element to the DOM, get its computed dimensions, remove that element to the DOM, and do it so fast that the browser does **not** hit a frame render in between (among other things, because the browser UI thread is blocked while doing so).

This is how Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision works: Add everything to the DOM (add all the leaflet layers to the map), get the computed style for everything, add the bounding boxes to the `rbush` structure, compute collisions, remove elements from the DOM (layers from the map) *within one frame*.

Comment: "Use window.getComputedStyle after the element has been added to the DOM." Not an option. As I have already described in the question, I need to get the sizes of the labels before I draw them. You suggest that I should draw them and then read their dimensions. But I need their dimensions to know where to draw them, so if they are already drawn, then I am no longer interested in their dimensions.

Comment: "You are free to remove that element from the DOM" Not an option. If it is already there, then I am not interested to fix its position and I have good reason not to do that which I will not delve into to keep things simple. Long story short: I wonder whether there is any way to get the dimensions of a leaflet label before drawing it. Your opinion is that there is no way to do that. I can measure the labels and see how wide they are if a parapgraph contains n letters if there is no better option and reuse these sizes, so actually there is a way, but involves labor-intense research.

Comment: "This is how Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision works" I compute this mathematically without reading from the DOM and when I know where to place things I draw the markers. This works perfectly if we ignore the problem with labels. And I can pre-measure the labels in different cases and in different browsers and in different stylings, but that takes a while. There is a solution, but it is painful. I understand your opinion is that there is no other way. You might be right, but let's wait for other answers as well to see if there still is some additional info.

Comment: I get your point that you want to do things "right", but you are bound to the limitations of a DOM whether you like it or not. Any techniques you might want to try to achieve this (such as [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)) will ultimately take much more time than an add-measure-remove approach (and sooner or later you'll hit edge cases).

Comment: And I know it's easy to compute things when you're dealing with simple shapes such as semicircumferences and images with known sizes in pixels. But when it comes to labels, you introduce text, so you introduce variable typefaces, and kerning, and combining UTF8 characters, and per-browser defaults, and calculating that is hard. **Very hard**. So hard that it's computationally cheaper to let the browser do it, not to speak the difficulty of fetching typeface metrics in your code.

Comment: You might want to try an approach based on [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText), but sooner or later you'll hit edge cases with CSS styling not being applied to the text you're measuring, which you'll notice in the form of glitches. And you won't be saving any time, because renderToCanvas→measureCanvas→addToDom will take more time than addToDom→measureDom→removeDom: the former renders the text twice, the latter renders the text once.